# Failed to parse column picker rules - azure ML designer

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to use the azure ML designer (preview).

referencing this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-designer-automobile-price-train-score

using my own input sheet which has four columns and some decimal values. nothing fancy and identical to the sample datasets provided.

I do this step (from the linked document above)

*Select the Train Model module.
In the module details pane to the right of the canvas, select Edit column selector.
In the Label column dialog box, expand the drop-down menu and select Column names.
In the text box, enter price to specify the value that your model is going to predict.*

and I get this (but there are no errors in the actual designer window.

"Failed to parse column picker rules"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found an answer myself. Hope that is okay.

In my input sheet, the title was something like this "Interest Rate %". Looks like azure was trying to say that it does not like special characters it the column names.

I edited my original csv file in excel, and removed the % in all the titles.

Then, created a new data store. problem solved.

Comment: I marked my own answer as answer Q ^ A style. I am hoping thats okay as it solved my issue.